# Inline Function more or less safe

Tags: c++, function, inline

Is "inline" safer, or less safe than using a pre-compiler definition for "max" (see below)?

```
#define max(a,b)    (a > b) ? a : b
```

Given this function definition:

```
inline int max (int a, int b)
{
  return (a > b) ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? I'd always prefer inline functions over macros whenever possible

Comment: in C++, it is encouraged to use `inline` over `define`.

Comment: Preprocessor macros are [evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/inline-vs-macros.html) (for [certain definitions of evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/defn-evil.html)).

Answer (score 8):

There's a semantic difference:

```
max(pay_wife(1000), get_salary());
```

Comment: One of the coolest analogies I've ever seen to explain 'semantic difference"

Answer (score 4):

The macro version will evaluate its arguments multiple times which will result in semantic difference (error) if the argument has side effects (like calling a non-const function).

Further the arguments aren't each enclosed in parens so there may be *other* ways you can concoct parameters such that precedence completely changes the meaning of what's being attempted. For example `max(c, x < y)` would fold out as `(c > x < y) ? c : x < y` which will evaluate `c > x` and then compare the truth of that against `y`. That's completely not what was intended.

The inline function on the other hand works only with integral types without truncations.

A better approach is to not reinvent the wheel and use `std::max` which takes care of all the problems above and is handily provided by your implementation.

Comment: And the 'result' isn't parenthesised either so `max(100,2) + 1` may not produce the "expected" answer.

Comment: Maybe you could mention `std::max` as well, as it provides everything your last paragraph describes.

Comment: @lethal-guitar Good call: I removed my note about writing your own function in favor of not reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

The macro has many negative side-effects. For example consider

```
max( ++a, b );
```